# Unable to determine the DbProviderFactory type for connection of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have Asp.net MVC application developed with EF 6.0.

When I run it from soruce code it works completely fine. But when I deployed the application on Windows server 2016 machine it shows below message on page.

***Error: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct. :Unable to determine the DbProviderFactory type for connection of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.***

Can anyone help me to sort out the issue please?

below is the web.config file of the application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>



    <add name="TitanSQLConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ukpdpmc3;Initial Catalog=Titan;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TitanLiveSQLConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ukpdpmc3;Initial Catalog=Titan;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DMSSQLConnection" connectionString="data source=ukpdpmc3;initial catalog=DMS;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TitanTestSQLConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ukpdpmc3;Initial Catalog=Titan;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <!--<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://ukpdc01.uk.nex.global/OU=IT,OU=Central Functions,OU=NEXUK Users,DC=uk,DC=nex,DC=global" />-->
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://ukpdc01.uk.nex.global/DC=uk,DC=nex,DC=global" />
    <add name="PartnerDbSQLConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ukpdpmc3;Initial Catalog=PartnersDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PartnerLiveSQLConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ukpdpmc3;Initial Catalog=PartnersDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PartnerTestSQLConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ukpdpmc5;Initial Catalog=PartnersDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="NXLookupSQLConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ukpdpmc3;Initial Catalog=NXlookup;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="nxsmartapi_pub_SmartApi1_Binder">
          <readerQuotas  maxStringContentLength="65536" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://ukpdsagis4.uk.nex.global:306/ws/nxsmartapi.pub.SmartApi1/nxsmartapi_pub_SmartApi1_Port" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="nxsmartapi_pub_SmartApi1_Binder" contract="SmartApi.SmartApi1_PortType" name="nxsmartapi_pub_SmartApi1_Port" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
    <!--<add key="ADDOMAIN" value="ukpdc01.uk.nex.global" />-->
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ProductFamilyId" value="19" />
    <add key="ProductCategoryId" value="5" />
    <add key="ProductBrandId" value="1" />
    <add key="PrintTemplateId" value="0" />
    <add key="SerialRequired" value="false" />
    <add key="VatCodeId" value="0" />
    <add key="ValidityPeriod" value="S" />
    <add key="RefundTypeId " value="0" />
    <add key="PrintCoupon " value="true" />
    <add key="MinPriority" value="1" />
    <add key="MaxPriority" value="12" />
    <!--Key for deloyment type e.g. dev and live -->
    <add key="DeploymentMode" value="dev" />
    <!--Keys for SmartApi service-->
    <add key="SalesChannel" value="Web" />
    <add key="AgentCode" value="007" />
    <add key="PartnerCode" value="NX" />
    <add key="CampaignCode" value="DEFAULT" />
    <add key="UserId" value="userid" />
    <add key="SmartApiUsername" value="SMART" />
    <add key="SmartApiPassword" value="smart" />
  </appSettings>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" throwExceptions="true" internalLogFile="c:\nlog.txt">

    <!-- make sure to set 'Copy To Output Directory' option for this file -->
    <!-- go to http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file for more information -->

    <targets>
      <target xsi:type="Database" name="DMSLogger" connectionString="Data Source=ukpdpmc3;Initial Catalog=PartnersDB;Integrated Security=True" dbDatabase="PartnersDB">
        <commandText>INSERT INTO DMSLog([LogLevel], [Message], [Exception], [createDate]) VALUES (@logLevel, @message, @exception, @createDate)</commandText>
        <parameter name="@createDate" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}" />
        <parameter name="@logLevel" layout="${level}" />
        <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
        <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:format=Message,StackTrace}" />

        <dbProvider>System.Data.SqlClient</dbProvider>
        <connectionString>Data Source=ukpdpmc3;Initial Catalog=DMS;Integrated Security=True</connectionString>
      </target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="DMSLogger"></logger>
    </rules>
  </nlog>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml">
      <error redirect="~/Error/Index" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <!--<authentication mode="Windows">
      --><!--<forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />--><!--
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>-->
    <!--<membership defaultProvider="ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web,          Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" applicationName="FormsWithADAuth" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
      </providers>
    </membership>-->
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>

    <!-- Glimpse: This can be commented in to add additional data to the Trace tab when using WebForms
        <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" enabled="true" pageOutput="false"/> -->
    <httpModules>
      <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

      <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

      <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.Odbc" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
  <runtimePolicies>
        <ignoredTypes>
        <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet" />
        </ignoredTypes>
  </runtimePolicies>
  </glimpse>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You need to install SQL Server libraries in production server with same version as your local one.

Comment: It does not work even if I deploy it on my machine but while same I run it from source code from my machine it works

Comment: Maybe is the application pool...I remember having had a similar problem

Comment: Check your server's platform. If it's 64-bit with 32-bit SQL Server installed, make sure that 32-bit support is enabled inside application pool.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I have enable 32-bit support in application pool but still the issue is not resolved